# Why does this TypeScript mixin employing generics fail to compile?

Tags: typescript, generics, traits, mixins, typescript-generics

I'm using mixins/traits with TypeScript using a subclass factory pattern as described at https://mariusschulz.com/blog/mixin-classes-in-typescript.  The trait in question is called `Identifiable`, which imparts an `id` property to a class that should express the `Identifiable` trait.  When I attempt to use the trait with another, non-generic trait (`Nameable`) in a certain order, compilation fails.

```
class Empty {}

type ctor<T = Empty> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function Nameable<T extends ctor = ctor<Empty>>(superclass: T = Empty as T) {
  return class extends superclass {
    public name?: string;
  };
}

function Identifiable<ID, T extends ctor = ctor<Empty>>(superclass: T = Empty as T) {
  return class extends superclass {
    public id?: ID;
  };
}

class Person1 extends Nameable(Identifiable<string>()) { // compiles
  constructor(name?: string) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = "none";
  }
}

class Person2 extends Identifiable<string>(Nameable()) { // fails to compile
  constructor(name?: string) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = "none";
  }
}
```

Compilation error is

```
src/test/unit/single.ts:30:10 - error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Person2'.

30     this.name = name;
            ~~~~
```

How do I get generic traits to compile correctly, regardless of the order in which they're used?

*NB: public git repo for this question is at https://github.com/matthewadams/typetrait.  If you want to play with this, make sure to checkout the `minimal` branch.*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Question is now absolutely minimal. Appreciate any help given.

Comment: I haven't used generic traits (looks interesting!). But great job reducing this!! Looks really answerable now. I pinged a guy I know.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ty -- let's hope I get some traction.  This is a real blocker for me.  :/

Comment: @MatthewAdams thanks for reducing the code, I wanted to look at it too but was put off by too much code to look through

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is very simple actually, and it is related to the fact that typescript does not have partial type argument inference. The call `Identifiable<string>(...)` does not mean you set `ID` and let the compiler infer `T`. It actually means use `string` for `ID` and use the default (ie `Empty`) for `T`. This is unfortunate and there is a [proposal to allow partial inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) but it hasn't gained much traction.

You have two options, either use function currying to do a two call approach, where the first call passes `ID` and the second call infers `T`:

```
class Empty { }

type ctor<T = Empty> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function Nameable<T extends ctor = ctor<Empty>>(superclass: T = Empty as T) {
  return class extends superclass {
    public name?: string;
  };
}

function Identifiable<ID>() {
  return function <T extends ctor = ctor<Empty>>(superclass: T = Empty as T) {
    return class extends superclass {
      public id?: ID;
    };
  }
}


class Person2 extends Identifiable<string>()(Nameable()) {
  constructor(name?: string) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = "none";
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECiC2AHALgT2gb2gXwFC7UQFNphkB7AJwB4AVaAXjiTQD5HoA7Igd2gAoAdMLCUA5hABc0MJ1QBtALoBKRu1oBufADMArpzIBLcp2gA5MPCJgARiCJ1oRAB7IinACYwyVDj5oIKKisrPwQusSUoJBS0PRMgWgyMLSqGLjQ0JREyLqUptFQTq7uXtDhkYUw6ZmZiLp2hsBclkQA-NIQyJSGnGJamdhaeLh6BsjGpgCSHu4T2oa29tRTACKhaRlZOXmmY0Ym0I4ubp7eFJR+F9SJwaEVRFHgUNLxzEHJcZu127n5pM8YCdSjAHk8Ypgtj96o1moYPB1oGsBrUhls8CNcFVoAAFR4QEwAJmKpzKMzmhgWSwcXR6fQ2-AsVmp-GU31IJlpun8-E4rURtN6YnZmTBrJRmWQAAtDBBBHyrBwFUQJdBpbLBPCOAAiTgmIjalEYoA)

Or use inference on `ID` as well by using a dummy parameter as an inference site:

```
class Empty { }

type ctor<T = Empty> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

function Nameable<T extends ctor = ctor<Empty>>(superclass: T = Empty as T) {
  return class extends superclass {
    public name?: string;
  };
}

function Identifiable<ID, T extends ctor = ctor<Empty>>(type: ID, superclass: T = Empty as T) {
    return class extends superclass {
      public id?: ID;
    };
  }
}


class Person2 extends Identifiable(null! as string, Nameable()) {
  constructor(name?: string) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = "none";
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECiC2AHALgT2gb2gXwFC7UQFNphkB7AJwB4AVaAXjiTQD5HoA7Igd2gAoAdMLCUA5hABc0MJ1QBtALoBKRu1oBufADMArpzIBLcp2gA5MPCJgARiCJ1oRAB7IinACYwyVDj5oIKKisrPwQusSUoJBS0PRMgWgyMLSqGLjQ0JREyLqUptFQTq7uXtDhkYUw6ZmZiLp2hsBclkQA-NIQyJSGnGJamdhaeLh6BsjGpgCSHu4T2oa29tRTACIANHHFbp7eFJR++9SJwaGERNJrmxVEUeBQ0vHMQclxaRm12bn5pPcwLjsyjc7jFMB9atB6o1moYPB1oGsBrUhh88CNcFVoAAFW4QEwAJm2pRgMzmhgWSyI-E4uhAIAAhK8uj0+psLFZKfxlO9MsATMzdP5qa14czemIebVgVykZlkAALQwQQScVocVVWWXQBVKwSwjgAIk4JiIBqRaKAA)

Comment: Thanks, @titian-cernicova-dragomir.  I tried one more variation, https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECiC2AHALgT2gbwL4CgdsQFNphkB7AJwB4AVaAXjiTQD4HoA7Qgd2gAoAdELAUA5hABc0MB1QBtALoBKBmxoBuPAWIA5MsgAWASw6j2pSlQQpULTTgBmAVw6kjZDtB1h4hMACMQQlpoQgAPZEIOABMYCwpzcmprVhY+CCciClBISWg6RhT0SHyVDBxoaApCZCcKTxyoUIio2OgMrMaYcsrKxCdAo2BOH0IAfikIZAoTUU1KrE1cRxc3D2gASWio5CMHIwCgqg2AEQAafObImLiktI7CbPAoKQKmG2kYGjKKqpq6hrPGDha5tB5PXKYX59AYgIbQIzRCabE7zaCLHDLLrQAAKjwgHgATFdWjAtjs9gdAsEpjNTBc9IZZmlvL5DoQ+EofpVgB5aU54nwOKNkbTZtzeuDOWjKkyIAJhb52IrCDLoHKBIj2AAiDgeQjatG4XBAA but it's broken.  Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, the change when using `Identifiable`:  `class Person2 extends Identifiable<string, Nothing>(Nameable()) { ... }`.  Here I'm trying not to use inference at all by explicitly listing the type parameters.

Comment: @MatthewAdams But if `name` does not flow from `Nameable()` to `Identifiable` to the class where is `name` supposed to come from ?  If you want to use explicit types, this would be a version that works:

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECiC2AHALgT2gbwL4CgdsQFNphkB7AJwB4AVaAXjiTQD4HoA7Qgd2gAoAdELAUA5hABc0MB1QBtALoBKBmxoBuPAWIA5MsgAWASw6j2pSlQQpULTTgBmAVw6kjZDtB1h4hMACMQQlpoQgAPZEIOABMYCwpzcmprVhY+CCciClBISWg6RhT0SHyVDBxoaApCZCcKTxyoUIio2OgMrMaYcsrKxCdAo2BOH0IAfikIZAoTUU1KrE1cRxc3D2gASWio5CMHIwCgqg2AEQAafObImLiktI7CbPAoKQKmG2kYGjKKqpq6hrPGDha5tB5PXKYX59AYgIbQIzRCabE7zaCLHDLLrQAAKjwgHgATFdWjAtjs9gdAsEpjNTBd4lQMCNfMjabN0Sw0t5fIdCHwlD9KsAPLSnPE+BxRmzprMhb1wQK0ZVDEYIAIpb52JrCMroKr1Yj2AAiDgeQjGtG4XBAA

Comment: Ah, ok.  I say yuck on that.  I'll stick with typed dummy arguments until TypeScript resolves the issue.  Thanks again!  :)