# Applying a typescript mix-in to a generic base class to obtain a generic derived class

Tags: typescript, mixins, typescript-generics

In typescript, I have defined an interface with a type parameter `T`.  It's for some kind of container over values of type `T`, which can be implemented in multiple way.  Some of the methods on the interface need to be specialized for each implementation.  But other methods can be given a generic implementation (over `T`) where the result can be obtained solely by calling the core methods.  So I thought I could implement this by using a *mix-in* to extend a class that just implements the core methods to one that implements all of the methods.

But I've not been able to discover valid typescript syntax that will apply a mix-in to a generic base class to produce a generic derived class.

Let me give a simplified example.  I split my interface into a core part (`Base<T>`) and a derived part (`Derived<T>`).

```js
interface Base<T> {
    foo(x: number): T[];
}

interface Derived<T> extends Base<T> {
    doubleFoo(x: number): T[];
}
```

I can implement a class on the base interface, say like this:

```js
class BaseImpl<T> implements Base<T> {
    constructor(public t: T) {}

    foo(x: number) {
        return new Array(x).fill(this.t);
    }
}
```

Now I want to write a mix-in function that given `BaseImpl` will return a class that implements `Derived`.  Both base and derived implementation classes should still have `T` as a type parameter.

I initially tried the following:

```js
type Constructor<I> = new (...args: any[]) => I;

const MixInDoubleFoo = <T, C extends Constructor<Base<T>>> (BaseClass: C) => {
    return class extends BaseClass implements Derived<T> {

        doubleFoo(x: number) {
            return this.foo(x * 2);
        }
    }
}

const DerivedImpl = MixInDoubleFoo(BaseImpl);
```

This compiles without error.  But it seems that the resulting class has lost some type information.  When I tried the following I got an error.

```js
class MyDerivedFromMixin<T> extends DerivedImpl<T> {

    tripleFoo(x: number): T[] {
        // error: Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
        // error:   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        // error:     'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.
        return this.foo(3 * x);
    }
}
```

For contrast if I try to extend the base implementation class in exactly the same way it compiles without error.

```js
class MyDerivedFromBaseImpl<T> extends BaseImpl<T> {

    tripleFoo(x: number): T[] {
        return this.foo(3 * x);
    }
}
```

It appears to me that the typescript type inference failed to view `T` as a type parameter of the function returned from the mix-in, but replaced it with `unknown`.

I read over this question: [Why does this TypeScript mixin employing generics fail to compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57347557/why-does-this-typescript-mixin-employing-generics-fail-to-compile).  The situation in that question is different - the questioner is trying to add a type parameter into the mix-in function, whereas I am trying to lift up a type parameter from the base class.

Nevertheless it did tell me that typescript does not infer types when some, but not all, of the template parameters are provided.  I experimented with both solutions suggested there (currying the mixin function, providing an extra dummy parameter to make type inference simpler).  But although I tried lots of different syntaxes, none of them were acceptable to the compiler.

What I want to end up with is a mix-in which will allow me to write `DerivedImpl = MixIn(BaseImpl)` so that I can then:

- Create an instance of the class: `const instance = new DerivedImpl<T>(...)`
- Extend it as a class parameterized over `T`: `class Extension<T> extends DerivedImpl<T> { ... }`

Is there any way to do this?  I'm starting to think that I should just give-up on trying to use a mix-in, and just make the '*derived*' methods into template functions over `T` that take an instance of the base class.  That will obviously work, it just seems somewhat ugly.

---

Typescript playground containing all code from above: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QDwBUB8yA3gLABQylyMA9jQBQAeAXMiAK4C2ARtAJStcAbQC6AbnIBfcuVCRYiFABFowAG4QAJnkIRGkEJoxpMOAsXJVkmmu24AbCADE6TVhx79BoiWWllyBHtMY3QsAElOAAd7HWRgaMdOCHBQ0zjSCioEGhAMMCh2BDAaKHoou3tgBGQwQT5iZH9LKloGFjYuXigGzKsrKAgwdigQNggAd2QAQSgoOABPJj4AOhhge3t6MAALYAwVsD5fK39msjAFqJQAYVz8wuLS7HDCAF5xqfoVn7goAHMMKw4CAFqIGm9COFfIF7mBkABZYCMcIgJS2BzOOjID54AA0yBuyD0BiMhLhjxKUGwYTM+Hp9FpN2CGCBhIhhD6VEGw1GyCCIWJ+hSZKZLOMCRiEGSqWQKig6i0GRkWX61gxjhc7XcXX4FlVau5QxGY12+zWrkYyAAVMgAEzHFpq-ynKQqnJ5eHyxWaSIxHGI5Go9GVLEMWl++yOgJkAWsxELb0aTROKA0ThIxigOIkkXGJNaSPKmNWArAKVatydTw9bwifWG5AAeibxLmpUEVxQAHJ2CAANYgGgTECibvxYxD+EhYD-EBwTG1Gi1LvIbvCETdlZO-otttpqCsSi4Ve9gdDkfj-ZsGjT1mz+eLkor65r3BbndWPfQA9Hqjr8ccnYexNGQXh4k9EEwGAOBIFAiZgF2ZAQWQqBuEQ+YoAWF8UAmPYEB2flbBAsCUD7QZgjgpc1z7QdhxAD8DQGY0+TNA42noABmG1kEYaNXT8d1xQTAsUzTTgI0SHNhUMNIIik8xMh3MsK0tHUawEZANwbQ09wAOWXH9Sk-I1eVNPZ2NcbjbT4k4qHOfwgA)

I'm using typescript 3.9.